# Your Magento cron seems to not be running

Tags: magento, cron

I have copied production to staging and updated the `local.xml` file and the base_urls. Its now giving me warning 
        Warning! Your Magento cron seems to not be running. You need this 
        for your Moogento extensions to run well.
New to magento don't know how to proceed please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the cron is running on your staging environment.
Run `crontab -e` in your console and inside the editor add this line

```
*/5 * * * * sh /path/to/magento/root/cron.sh
```